# R binning a categorical age group

Tags: r

[image]

I am trying to group the twitterAge in categorical bins. and add them to a  new column to show the twitter age group in my
dataframe based on twitterAge by converting it into the following groupings or categories like the one below

[‘0-1’,’1-2’,’2-3’,’3-4’, ‘4-5’, ‘5+’]

‘0-1’ refers to the ages equal to older than 0 and younger then 1. Using the same logic for other age groups. the next would be older than 1 and younger than 2 .. etc
5+ is essentially referring to older than 5 but younger than 6

my approach is like this but I am afraid it wrong

```
breakpoints <- c(0,1,2,3,4,5,6)
name <-  c(‘0-1’,’1-2’,’2-3’,’3-4’, ‘4-5’, ‘5+’)
# my data file name is twitter_data
twitter_data$twitterAgeGroup <- cut(twitter_data$twitterAge,breaks = breakpoint,labels = name)
```

would this be the approach suitable?

Comment: Do you have any data beyond 6? This approach would give `NA` for those values.

Comment: no i have checked and the biggest value is 5.6

Comment: would changing the breakpoint = c(0,1,2,3,4,5,Inf) be better?

Comment: Yes, that would be better but in your case (if your max value is 5.6) it would not change the output.

Comment: also i think i should change breakpoint = c(-Inf,1,2,3,4,5,Inf)